# VB6 insert data into excel from database

Tags: excel, ms-access, vb6, ado

I have been looking for a solution to inserting data into excel using vb6 code and access database. There are many cases where I need to write to an excel spreadsheet multiple times with different records of data. I have an existing workbook that I am trying to open and "save as" when I am complete. I have been able to open the excel workbook, access the sheet I am writing to, and the cells I am writing to, however I can only write to the workbook once and when I leave the scope of the open workbook the connection is closed.

I have a sub routine that creates the workbook object, opens the existing workbook and work sheet, writes to a specified cell number to insert the new data. I have looked at [official support pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/247412/methods-for-transferring-data-to-excel-from-visual-basic) and it doesn't seem to have what I am looking for at this time.

Am I making this too complicated or is there a solution for this? Please help.

My current code:

Row Arrays

```
Private oldDataRowArray(3 To 21) As Integer
Private updatedDataRowArray(5 To 2) As Integer
```

Loop logic

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
i = 3
n = 5
Do While i <= UBound(oldDataRowArray) And n <= UBound(updatedDataRowArray)
EditExcelSheet txtWorkbookFileName.Text, i, n //sub routine
i = i + 3 //skip number of cells
n = n + 3 //skip number of cells
Loop
```

Sub Routine to Insert data into Excel

```
Private Sub EditStakingSheet(ByVal workbook As String, ByVal oldDataRowIndex As Integer, ByVal newDataRowIndex As Integer)
Dim objExcel As Object
Dim objWorkBook As Object
Dim objSheet As Object

Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(workbook)
Set objSheet = objWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

objExcel.Visible = True
//insert old value
objSheet.Cells(oldDataRowIndex , 26).Value = "old Value"

//insert new value
objSheet.Cells(newDataRowIndex , 26).Value = "new Value"

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by: "so far I have been able to open the excel workbook, target the sheet, and the cells I am writing to, however I can only write to the workbook once and when I leave the scope of the open workbook the connection is gone.". Can you post the code as you should be able too use VB6 to connect to Access and then write data into Excel.

Answer (score -2):

You could use adodb objects.

[This video is a good tutorial for this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HE9CIbetNnI)

Here is an example how you can use adodb. You need to install the activeX Data Objects Libary for this.
For `.source=` you  can use any sql-query.

```
Public Function get_Value(table As String, order_by As String) As Variant

Set db_data = New ADODB.Recordset

Set db1 = New ADODB.Connection

pDB_path = "#enter db-path here"

db1.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & pDB_path & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

db1.Open


With db_data
    .ActiveConnection = db1
    .Source = "SELECT * FROM " & table & " ORDER BY " & order_by & " ASC"
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly 'read only access to db
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic 'how to update the database
    .Open
End With

get_Value = TransposeArray(db_data.GetRows)

db_data.Close

End Function
```